# How to select year and month from the datepicker-Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, datepicker

Am trying to select **Year** and **Month** from the drop down but it is in the form of datepicker. I can't able to target by ID and it's selecting the value by class. Please anyone can give me sample code in java with javascript executor.

Here is my html tag:

```
<div id="ui-monthpicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 413.8px; left: 998.9px; z-index: 1; display: none;">

<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">

<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" title="Prev" onclick="MP_jQuery_1386732165275.monthpicker._adjustDate('#fromMonth', -1, 'Y');">

<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>

</a>
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" title="Prev"      onclick="MP_jQuery_1386732165275.monthpicker._adjustDate('#fromMonth', +1, 'Y');">

<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Prev</span>
</a>

<div class="ui-datepicker-title">

<select class="ui-datepicker-year" onchange="MP_jQuery_1386732165275.monthpicker._selectYear('#fromMonth', this, 'Y');">

<option value="2010">2010</option>

<option value="2011">2011</option>

<option value="2012">2012</option>

<option selected="selected" value="2013">2013</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Comment: share the source of the html that you are trying to select please

Comment: any one please suggest me some solution

Comment: Did you try using the `Select()` class? Something like `WebElement datePicker = Select(driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")); datePicker.selectByVisibleText("2010");`

Answer (score 1):

1.For finding the element property you can use xpath reference from its parent elements, in your case you can use id="ui-monthpicker-div" or similar one which u feel free

2.For selecting the drop down  using its value you can use following similar code

Select select = new Select(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-monthpicker-div']//select[1]"));
select.selectByValue("2010");

Please let me know if it helps :)

Comment: If adding your above code am getting webdriver cannot be resolved in the line new Select(webdriver

Answer (score 0):

try this,

http://seleniumcapsules.blogspot.com/2012/10/design-of-datepicker.html,

1. an icon used as a trigger;
2. display a calendar when the icon is clicked;
3. Previous Year button(<<), optional;
4. Next Year Button(>>), optional;
5. Previous Month button(<);
6. Next Month button(>);
7. day buttons;
8. Weekday indicators;
9. Calendar title i.e. "September, 2011" which representing current month and current year.